# Errors calling uidna_labelToUnicode - converting international domain name to unicode

Tags: unicode, icu

I'm trying to convert an international domain name label (punycode encoded) to unicode using the ICU UIDNA library. I think I'm setting up the call to `uidna_labelToUnicode()` correctly, but I get an error count of 1024. At the same time, the status indicates success. (Which seems contradictory)

Here's my code:

```
#include <unicode/uidna.h>
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <unicode/ustring.h>
#include <unicode/utypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char* icustring2char(icu::UnicodeString convertme) {
    std::string result;
    convertme.toUTF8String(result);
    return result.c_str();
}

const char* icuchar2char(UChar* convertme) {
        icu::UnicodeString temp(convertme);
        return icustring2char(temp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        UErrorCode err = U_ZERO_ERROR;
        UIDNA* uidna = uidna_openUTS46(UIDNA_CHECK_BIDI, &err);

        UChar label[64];
        UChar output[64];
        int32_t output_length = 64;
        UIDNAInfo info = UIDNA_INFO_INITIALIZER;
        UErrorCode status;
        status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
        int32_t buflen = u_unescape("xn--test-", label, 64);
        output_length = uidna_labelToUnicode(uidna, label, buflen, output, output_length, &info, &status);

        printf("error count: %u\n", info.errors);

        if (U_FAILURE(status)) {
                printf("error: %s\n", u_errorName(status));
        }
        else {
                printf("success\n");
                printf("result: %s\n", icuchar2char(output));
        }

        return 0;
}
```

The output is...

```
error count: 1024
success
result: ������
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated.